# Sort number in string with $ SQL

Tags: sql, string

How do i sort following strings in ascending order using SQL? I want the order to be in numerical order.

```
$15.00
$20.00
$5.00
$100.00
$1.00
```

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: For money, you should in general use a column type of `DECIMAL(19,4)`. Then you put the currency symbol in front of when it comes to *displaying* the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all have the same format -- a dollar sign, some numbers, a decimal point, and two digits following the decimal point -- then you can use this trick:

```
order by length(col) asc, col asc
```

Some databases spell `length()` as `len()`.

If the strings don't all have a uniform format, then you should convert them to a number for sorting.  How you do that depends on the database, which is not tagged.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server then you can do it the below way or the first way is to get the column datatype converted

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP.TEST1 ( SALE VARCHAR(25))
INSERT INTO TEMP.TEST1 VALUES
( '$15.00'),
('$20.00'),
('$5.00'),
('$100.00'),('$1.00')

SELECT SALE
FROM TEMP.TEST1 ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(SALE,'$','') AS NUMERIC(10,2))
```